# Can nodejs scripts be hidden from the node debugger?

Tags: node.js

If I'm importing encrypted scripts via:

```
const requireFromString = function(src, filename) {
    let m = new module.constructor();
    m.id = filename;
    m.paths = module.paths;
    m.filename = filename;
    m._compile(src, filename);
    return m.exports;
};
```

How can I hide those from the debugger, so if someone has access to the server running the node app, cannot see the scripts in any way?

Comment: If someone has enough access to your server to attach a debugger then they could probably also edit the code that you use to load your encrypted modules (and by that obtaining the source code) if the debugger was for some reason unavailable. I wouldn't bother with trying to stop the debugger, you've already lost if they get that far.

Comment: The specific use case is for partners that might share ssh keys of the deployment servers, but we don't want them to access the source code.  Currently there is a startup server validation sending the project's checksum and other data, if the script is modified, an invalid checksum is sent and no encryption key is returned.  But once decrypted, it's available through the debug console as any other script.

Comment: It seems to be not possible to garantie the protection of your source code in this context. Maybe try http://enclosejs.com/ or consider serving your app as SaaS.

Comment: Well they could just start a debugger or listen in on the traffic for your startup validation to retrieve the encryption key and then they have the source anyway. If possible you should restrict the permissions of the accounts they access the server with, unless of course they need to debug the app then your best bet would be to host the encrypted parts on another server and call it as an external service.

Comment: Found a solution, the script sending the data to fetch the encryption key, sends the checksum and is done via SSL and payload encryption, part of the data in the payload is a boolean that is true when debug mode is on, if the license server detects that the checksum does not match, or debug is true, it will reject the request.  Thanks for the comments everyone!